# How do i remove the arrow on a shortcut icon in C# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I've been making a program that takes icons from all the files in a directory to be able to launch it from the desktop in a neat way, i cant seem to find a way to remove the arrow on the icons though. Even editing regedit it only changes the icons in the folder itself, not in the program. This is how it looks right now; https://gyazo.com/de026d6e9bde7d7407dd6fe86026aaae

This is the code i use to extract the icon;
https://pastebin.com/LccwnaS3

If anyone is interested in how i use the code in the main form, here you go;

```
string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/Johnny/Desktop/Program/Spel", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

//removed the creation of pictureboxes


//paint event of each picturebox
int i = Convert.ToInt32(((PictureBox)sender).Name.Replace("pb", ""));
            Point p = new Point(0, 0);

            e.Graphics.DrawIconUnstretched(ExtractIcon.GetIcon(allfiles[i], false), new Rectangle(p, new Size(38, 38)));
```

Comment: [Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: The Icons are indexed by an `IImageList` Interface, which can be retrieved using the `SHGetImageList()` function. Then, you can use the [`IImageList::GetIcon()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commoncontrols/nf-commoncontrols-iimagelist-geticon) method to extract the Icon you want. This method also allows to extract the ExtraLarge and Jumbo icons. The method parameters also [accepts flags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/imagelistdrawflags) often used to get the Icon rendered with transparency. I.e., you're missing a couple of steps in that method.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That would work if i wasnt using shortcuts, but grabbing icons from shortcuts it doesnt work at all for me. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: @Jimi I'll look into that, i'm just a hobby programmer, so i have to learn abit more to truly understand what you mean. Thanks for the in-depth answer ^^

Comment: Shortcuts are better resolved when you need the *good* icon. There's another interface, `IShellLinkW`, usually cast from a class object (i.e., `IShellLinkW shellLink = (IShellLinkW)new ShellLink();`, where `ShellLink` is `[ComImport, Guid("00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")] public class ShellLink { }`). This class can also be cast to yet another interface, `IPersistFile`, which is used to load and save a Link object (well, the Windows Shell is a long, long story).

Comment: Note that the Icon referenced in a Link object can be part of the executable or a `dll` (the resource index is provided) or an actual Icon, stored somewhere (often, in the Installer repository, but it could be in the application path). In this case, the property value returns the path to the Icon file.